# Angular2 firing validation by default

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I am using `FormBuilder` and have simple validation which checking if field is valid with `*ngIf="!field.valid`

```
<input [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['field']"
       type="text" id="field"  #field="ngForm">
<span class="error" *ngIf="!field.valid">Error</span>
```

Always when components are loaded the `errors` are shown before I even type anything in any inputs. How to stop Angular 2 of running validation on component load so it fires only when typing?

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are three types of error class for inputs of form,

- dirty - when Control's value has changed
- touched - when Control has been visited
- valid - when Control's value is valid(as per validation provided)

so as per your requirements you need to use `dirty or touched` class from among classes,
you can use `[hidden] as well as *ngIf` to use this error class (to show error message).
you could use like this:

```
<span [hidden]="name.valid" *ngIf='name.touched'><b>Required</b></span>
```

see [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/obYk0tMDfNK9l71UyhIA?p=preview) for form using error classes.

for more info related to error classes see here

- http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: When you go to submit the form you'd want any fields that are invalid, but untouched to now show their error messages. How would you do that?

Comment: this.myForm.markAsTouched();
if (this.myForm.valid) {// your code} else {// display custom errors}

Answer (score 1):

Include a check if the field is `touched` or `dirty`

```
<span class="error" *ngIf="!field.valid && field.dirty">Error</span>
```